# Is it possible to replicate different Galera MAIN-MAIN clusters (MariaDB) with another Galera MAIN-MAIN cluster but as MAIN-SECONDARY asynchronously?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, galera

We are a small team of developers and we usually deal with single database access locally or remotely. We are working on a project that needs to have not only replication on the local network (we'll implement either a load balancer or a custom fallback for DB access) to try to achieve an SLA of 100% but also remote replication (on the cloud) for backup purposes.

I've been playing a little bit with Galera and managed to run a cluster locally (using some VMs) which run synchronously (emulating different nodes in a local network) and another cluster inside Azure. Everything works perfectly but we really don't know if we can connect asynchronously the nodes outside Azure (as slaves) to the cluster in Azure.

TL;DR: Here's what we have in mind in a graphic :)

[image: Quick diagram of what we'd like to achieve]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they replicating the _same_ data?  Or different, say, _databases_?

Comment: @RickJames exactly the same DBs. Each client will have their own server(s) in the cloud for backing up just his info

Comment: Sorry, your reply is ambiguous.  Is there any chance of a row coming from each source that has the same unique key?  This is especially critical if `AUTO_INCREMENT` is involved, sense they will be tracking independently on both source clusters.

Comment: Each cluster is in a single physical location?  So it is vulnerable to fires, earthquakes, floods, hurricanes, etc?  So, the comingled backup in the cloud is the recovery from a disaster?  Have you tested the recovery strategy?

Comment: Actually, each server within a local cluster will be physically separated from one another (different buildings or different cities even) and the MULTI-MASTER replication there would only be for anyone in that cluster to be able to fetch mostly historical data, even if the network is down and his or her office isolated from the rest of the network.

Yes, the DBs would have unique keys with auto incremental values, but I noticed Galera takes care of that by itself, at least in a MULTI-MASTER setup.

Comment: BTW, the cloud backup would serve two purposes: first as a backup in case of a disaster (or general cluster failure) and second as a backend for online access for clients, so I don't have to deal with local web servers in a per-client basis so, if they want to access their historical data using a web browser from their homes, they would access our cloud web server.

Comment: This question is really interesting - however, it is not a programming related question, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO deal with database admin questions like this.

Comment: @Shadow I know you are completely right. But I did many searches before posting and even I didn't find exactly what I was looking for (same scenario), most of the questions were asked here. Guess it's the defacto for many of us programmers. Maybe someone could move it?